# SVG placed in IMG tag not loading on Firefox & IE, works perfectly in Chrome

Tags: image, internet-explorer, firefox, svg

I am using an SVG through an img tag and it does not want to load through Firefox & IE. Here is the testing site.

http://testing.khalidsleiman.com/

You can find the SVG in the html by searching for a class called "mask". Placing the SVG directly in my html through an  tag works. Here is a direct link to it as well.

http://testing.khalidsleiman.com/img/main-mask.svg

I have looked through 40-50 similar problems people have experienced and have not found a solution yet. Have not clue why it wouldn't load.

Comment: It is loading and displaying in Firefox, what makes you think it's not?  It is the same colour as the background which doesn't really make it stand out (Remove everything else on the page including the styles and you'll see it).

Comment: When I hover over the source for the img in Firefox it is displaying a message saying "Could not load image". The img box is there but svg does not show.

Comment: It didn't do that for me. Perhaps you have an extension that's interfering with things. Try safe mode and/or a new profile.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on my website. No clue why the console can't fond the image in svg format while it can in png…
Though your link displays the img on my computer (tested with Firefox stable, FirefoxForDev37, Chromium41)

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `position: absolute;` and adjust the margin a bit, it seems to work fine in all three browsers.

```
.main-container .main-bg img.mask {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 101%;
}
```

I suspect an alternative to shifting it down with margin-bottom, would be to set `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet"` on the SVG.  That would force it to sit on the bottom of the viewport, instead of centred vertically as it is now (which I think is what is causing the gap).

Comment: Thanks! It showed up when I did that. Why would the absolute positioning cause it not to load? When i'd hover over the source Firefox would tell me that it could not load image.

Comment: I don't know the reason. :/

Comment: I had the same problem and removing absolute position solved he problem, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a .htaccess in the images folder solved my problem since the server did not support SVG.

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```